# Inversion of fractional ideals with respect to localization

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a integral domain with field of fractions $K$, $S$ is any multiplicative set in R and $\mathfrak M$ is a fractional ideal of $R$.

$$\mathfrak M^{-1}=\{x\in K:x\mathfrak M\subseteq{R}\}$$

Then $\mathfrak M_S=\mathfrak MR_S$ is a fractional ideal of $R_S$ and we have:

> $$(\mathfrak M^{-1})_S=(\mathfrak M_S)^{-1}$$

To see this, take $x\in(\mathfrak M^{-1})_S=\mathfrak M^{-1}R_S$.  Then $x=m/s$ with $m\in \mathfrak M^{-1}, s\in S$. Thus we have

$$x\mathfrak M_S=\frac{m}{s}\mathfrak M R_S=\frac{1}{s}m\mathfrak M R_S\subseteq \frac{1}{s}RR_S\subseteq R_S$$ i.e. $x\in (\mathfrak M_S)^{-1}$; this proves the inclusion "$\subseteq$".

This correct?

Help me for the inclusion "$\supseteq$".

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly proved $(R:\mathfrak M)_S\subseteq(R_S:\mathfrak M_S)$.

Let's prove $(R_S:\mathfrak M_S)\subseteq (R:\mathfrak M)_S$ whenever $\mathfrak M$ is *finitely generated*: if $x\mathfrak M_S\subseteq R_S$, then $xa_i\in R_S$ for $a_i\in\mathfrak M$ such that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is a system of generators. There is $s_i\in S$ with $s_ixa_i\in R$. For $s=\prod_{i=1}^ns_i$ we get $sxa_i\in R$. It follows that $sx\mathfrak M\subseteq R$, so $sx\in (R:\mathfrak M)$, and thus $x\in (R:\mathfrak M)_S$.

Comment: If $\mathfrak M$ is not finitely generated the containment  $(R:\mathfrak M)_S\subseteq(R_S:\mathfrak M_S)$ can be strict.